# How can I add a specific instance of a calendar serie using Google Calendar API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a recurring monthly event on the first Saturday of the month in my calendar
I have guests signing up by a form and want to add them to the specific date they selected

I wrote the following code in google-app-script to add the new guest to my event

- it works no problem if I do it on a single event
- if however I do it on an event serie, the new guest is added to all the instances

How do I modify it to only change the very instance I want? For example if my guest signed up for 'Saturday, 7 Oct 2023', how can I have this guest only added to that very instance?

Note:
I tried on a non-recurring event and this works well
I tried to look for an instance id in the API but unsuccesful
I searched stackoverflow and only found general instructions I could not apply (like: use the list method and the instances method)

```
`function addGuests(){
  var searchkey = 'Test Meeting';
  var newGuest = 'test@gmail.com';

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var calendarID = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getId();
  Logger.log('Calendar id: ' + calendarID );
  
  var startDate = new Date('Saturday, 2 Sept 2023');  
  console.log('starting on ' + startDate);

  var withinDay = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  console.log('starting on ' + withinDay);

  var events = calendar.getEvents(startDate, withinDay, {search: searchkey});
  Logger.log('Number of events: ' + events.length);

  event = events[0].getId();
  eventID = event.substring(0, event.indexOf('@'));
  Logger.log('Event id: ' + eventID );


  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarID, eventID);
  var attendees = event.attendees;
  attendees.push({email: newGuest});          
  var resource = { attendees: attendees };
  var args = { sendUpdates: "all" };
  Calendar.Events.patch(resource, calendarID, eventID, args);
}`
```